# How to make firefox open a closed tab in a new tab

Tags: firefox

When I select History::Recently Closed Tabs::Something, Firefox open that tab in the current tab, while I am used to Chrome that in the same situation open the tab in a new tab.

Is it possible to instruct Firefox to open a closed tab in a new tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is it possible to instruct Firefox to open a closed tab in a new tab?

It is possible with [Open Link with New Tab – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-GB)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/open-link-with-new-tab/):

> Open the link in a new tab depending on the setting.
>
> The following settings are possible
>
> - Follow the web page settings (Firefox Initial Settings)
> - Open a link to a different site on a tab
> - Open all links with tabs

I have it configured as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works